# Return the subset of NumPy array according to the first element of each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to get the subset *x* of the given NumPy array *alist* such that the first element of each row must be in the list *r*.

```
>>> import numpy 
>>> alist = numpy.array([(0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 2)])
>>> alist
array([[0, 2],
   [0, 4],
   [1, 3],
   [1, 4],
   [2, 1],
   [3, 1],
   [3, 2],
   [4, 1],
   [4, 3],
   [4, 2]])
>>> r = [1,3]
>>> x = alist[where first element of each row is in r] #this i need to figure out.
>>> x
array([[1, 3],
   [1, 4],
   [3, 1],
   [3, 2]])
```

Any easy way (without looping as I've a large dataset) to do this in Python?

Comment: I don't get why you don't want to loop? If you find frst occurance u can break the loop, but i don't see another way then checking first element, checking second and so on until you found it or there is no data left

Comment: @Lex native python loops are much slower than built-in numpy methods, which usually use compiled code under the hood.

Comment: If your question has been answered, consider accepting one of the solutions. Read more about it here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Slice the first column off input array (basically selecting first elem from each row), then use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with `r` as the second input to create a mask of such valid rows and finally index into the rows of the array with the mask to select the valid ones.

Thus, the implementation would be like so -

```
alist[np.in1d(alist[:,0],r)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [258]: alist   # Input array
Out[258]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 2]])

In [259]: r  # Input list to be searched for
Out[259]: [1, 3]

In [260]: np.in1d(alist[:,0],r) # Mask of valid rows
Out[260]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
                        False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [261]: alist[np.in1d(alist[:,0],r)] # Index and select for final o/p
Out[261]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the index array for the valid rows using some indexing tricks: we can add an additional dimension and check equality with each element of your first column:

```
import numpy as np
alist = np.array([(0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 1),
                     (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3), (4, 2)])

inds = (alist[:,0][:,None] == r).any(axis=-1)
x = alist[inds,:] # the valid rows
```

The trick is that we take the first column of `alist`, make it an `(N,1)`-shaped array, make use of array broadcasting in the comparison to end up with an `(N,2)`-shape boolean array, and if any of the values in a given row is `True`, we keep that index. The resulting index array is the exact same as the `np.in1d` one in [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41241701/5067311).

Comment: A shorter form : `alist[:,0,None] == r`.

Comment: @Divakar of course! \*facepalm\* Thank you, edited:)